# Why can't I access JS functions made in separate JS files in my html when using Meteor

Tags: meteor

Meteor says when you write some javascript in a JS file, every file automatically has access to it everywhere in the app, but when I write a function in a a separate file like that, I just get a console error saying that function could not be found when I call it in html. The only way I can get it to work is by writing the JS in the html file but I want to keep the languages separate. Any idea on what the problem is?

code:

html in one file:

```
<button onclick="dylan()"></button>
```

js in another file:

```
function dylan(){
   console.log("hello");
}
```

the problem is, when I click the button, it says dylan is not a function.

Comment: Please provide your code. What scope are you defining the functions in?

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen there is that good?

Comment: And is the script that contains the `dylan` function included in the HTML? For example: `<script src="dylan.js"></script>`

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen if its in the html it works, if its in its own file it doesnt work, that is the question

Comment: Nope, not talking about putting the code in the HTML, but rather including the `script` that has the JS in the HTML: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Answer (score 2):

Meteor docs do not spell this out but every individual javascript file is wrapped into a closure:

```
(function() { //the file content // })()
```

so all functions in a given file have their own scope.

Functions defined in a js file in Meteor normally only have file scope - that is, any object in that file can refer to them.

If you want to define a global function, create a global variable:

```
dylan = function(){
  ...
}
```

Note the absence of `let` or `var` which would restrict the function to file scope.

Now you can use this global in your `onclick` handler.

Note however, that normally in Meteor, you would define an event handler at the template level, ex:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click button'(){
    ...your code here
  }
});
```

As opposed to referring to event handlers in your html directly.

Comment: Rather than encouraging the bad practice of implicit globals, consider updating to use an explicit global reference, which will avoid the possible `ReferenceError` that crops up when the code gets called in strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of using Meteor is not met if you do not harness the wonderfull features such as 
**Template.X.events({});**,

**Template.X.helpers({});** and also

**Template.registerHelpers({});**

You can write your desired code in below way:

```
Template.template_name.events({
    'click .button_class' : function() {
         console.log("Hello");
     }
});

//HTML
<button class="button_class"></button>
```

If that click event has to be used in more than 1 HTML then you can use registerHelper methods than template click events.

```
Template.registerHelpers('dylan' : function() {
    console.log("Hello");
});

//html
<button onclick="dylan"></button>
```

Answer (score -1):

To access `dylan()`, you must first load the script file that contains that function into the html document.

You can do this by adding `<script src="myfile.js"></script>` anywhere before the button. (replace myfile with the name of your script)

Once loaded, `<button onClick="dylan()"></button>` will work!